# Way to display an empty date in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm modifying a C# Windows Form program using Visual Studio 2022 and am looking for a way to display an empty date field (preferably with two "/" to separate the day, month, and year).

The previous developer used a masked textbox which displayed "_*/__/*___" when a date isn't written, but the client wanted a more intuitive and easier way to write the date, which puts the cursor at the first position automatically, while also checking if the date is correct.

I thought of using a DateTimePicker since it automatically checks if the date written is correct or not, and it also features a calendar to make it easier, but the client doesn't like the fact that a date is displayed by default. I tried using a custom blank format but then the user need to select a date with the calendar and not manually for it to work and I know she will not like it.

Here is the code that I wrote : (the default format of the dtp is a custom one, displaying "  /  /    ".)

```
private void dtp_birthdate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtp_birthdate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
}

private void btn_enter_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dtp_birthdate.Format == DateTimePickerFormat.Custom)
    {
        lbl_errorMessage.Visible = true;
        errorProvider6.SetError(dtp_birthdate, "The birth date must be written!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make my dtp display an empty date while not using a custom format ? Should I use another type of textbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom DateTimePicker, `I didn't code it`, found it I believe here on Stackoverflow.

Simple usage

```
nullableDateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Control

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsLibrary.Controls
{

    public class NullableDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
    {
        private DateTimePickerFormat originalFormat = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        private string originalCustomFormat;
        private bool isNull;

        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public new DateTime Value
        {
            get => isNull ? DateTime.MinValue : base.Value;
            set
            {
                // incoming value is set to min date
                if (value == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    // if set to min and not previously null, preserve original formatting
                    if (!isNull)
                    {
                        originalFormat = Format;
                        originalCustomFormat = CustomFormat;
                        isNull = true;
                    }

                    Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    CustomFormat = " ";
                }
                else // incoming value is real date
                {
                    // if set to real date and previously null, restore original formatting
                    if (isNull)
                    {
                        Format = originalFormat;
                        CustomFormat = originalCustomFormat;
                        isNull = false;
                    }

                    base.Value = value;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCloseUp(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // on keyboard close, restore format
            if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
            {
                if (isNull)
                {
                    Format = originalFormat;
                    CustomFormat = originalCustomFormat;
                    isNull = false;
                }
            }

            base.OnCloseUp(eventArgs);
        }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);

            // on delete key press, set to min value (null)
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                Value = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if Value has a date or not
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public bool IsNullValue => Value == DateTime.MinValue;
    }
}
```